# How to add a listener to a grpc method?

Tags: java, grpc, rpc, grpc-java

I have a requirement to push the incoming request to a grpc method to a kafka topic. I am thinking of adding a listener for all the events to that method, so that the listener will do the job of pushing to kafka while my method can continue its processing.

Is there a way to add a listener to grpc methods?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your listener will be a small piece of code (or a function call) to push an event to Kafka and you can insert this piece of code either in a "unary call" method or a streaming call method. So I see this as independent of gRPC unless I am missing something. Take a look under https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples for both unary calls and streaming calls examples.